# How does UDP SetWriteBuffer and SetReadBuffer the OS's buffers?

Tags: sockets, go, udp, buffer

#### Description

I'm busy writing a high frequency UDP server with Go. I'd estimate at least 1000 packets/second both ways.

However as the size of data I'm sending over the UDP socket grew, I eventually ran into the follow error: `read udp 127.0.0.1:1541->127.0.0.1:9737: wsarecv: A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself.`

I eventually just grew the size of the buffers I was reading from and writing into as follows:

```
buffer := make([]byte, 64 * 1024 * 1024) // used to just be 1024
l, err := s.socketSim.Read(buffer)
```

This worked fine and I stopped getting the error... However then I can across two functions inside the `net` package:

```
s.socketSim.SetWriteBuffer(64 * 1024 * 1024)
s.socketSim.SetReadBuffer(64 * 1024 * 1024)
```

I learned that these two act on the `operating system's transmit buffer`

#### Question

Do I even care to set the operating system buffer size and why? How does the size on the application buffer impact the size of the operating system buffer? Should they always be the same and how big should/can they become?

Comment: Are you certain you want to be writing large UDP packets in the first place? The spec limits a UDP frame size to 65535, so you can't actually send a payload larger than 65507 (or 65527 on IPv6 IIRC). Even then, this requires jumbo frames be supported across the full link to prevent fragmentation (which would be 44 packets in most cases, with 44 times the chance of packet loss dropping the entire datagram)

Comment: The generally accepted practical limit for UDP datagram payloads is 534 bytes. Anything beyond that you're into IP fragmentation, and therefore increased risk of packet loss.

Comment: I'd rather avoid packet loss than using bigger payloads. So I'll keep the size according to spec. Still a bit confused why I'm given the option to change it... In which scenario would large UDP packets be ideal then?

Comment: @FanusduToit, large UDP packets work just fine when you control the network and know the MTU so they don't fragment. The read and write buffers are not the packet size, they are just the buffers for reading and writing, and you normally don't need to set those. Regardless of what you set the buffers to, you can't send more than 65535 bytes in a single packet, because the length field is only 16bits.

Comment: As a for-instance, if you're building a network that uses Ethernet jumbo frames (~9k) locally and your UDP connection is purely local, you then know that you can send 8KiB blocks of data as they'll just go in one jumbo frame. It's often wise to set such code up so that you _can_ handle more-conventional limits, though, as what was promised to be a local network often turns out, after the sales guys touch it, to have to play in the WAN space too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, not only do you have an MTU size for each interface on your device and whatever destination you're send/recving from, but there is also an MTU size for each device in between. For this reason, as others have mentioned, you might want to use what is generally accepted for MTU since you might not control every device in the data route. In the case of UDP, MTU really just means how big a datagram can be before fragmenting.

Second, you almost certainly want your SND/RCV buffers to be larger than the MTU. These are kernel buffers which hold on to data when you're not ready to receive them. A larger UDP RCV buffer means that the kernel will buffer more packets for you instead before dropping them into the abyss. Maybe you have some non-trivial work to do for each packet. Depending on the bitrate, you might want a larger or smaller kernel buffer.

Finally, you're using UDP. There is no guarantee that you'll receive packets in order or at all. Any router in between you and a peer could decide to drop the packet for any reason. Since you're using UDP, you should prepare for dropped and out-of-order packets. You also might need some sort of retransmission mechanism, which further complicates things.

Or you might consider using TCP if dropped packets are unacceptable, knowing that timing is indeterminate.

If you're on linux, you can see current buffer sizes in /proc/sys/net. Usually the kernel will double what you ask for.

Also, you can tune your buffer size by watching for packet drops in /proc/net/udp. If you see drops, you might want to make your rcv buffer bigger, especially if the data is bursty and the processing intensive. If you're data is coming in at a consistent rate and you're still dropping packets, then you aren't processing them fast enough.